Unable to find valid certification path to requested target ( CaCerts )
I'm having trouble integrating SSO ADFS with the Oauth2 security standard
Information about integration:
Github : https://github.com/millsofmn/oauth2-example
JDK: 8u391
Framework: Springboot
Content file application.yml
server:
  contextPath: /oauth2-example
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oauth2-example-master\oauth2-example-master\src\main\resources\keystore
    key-store-password: 123456a@
    keyStoreType: JKS
    keyAlias: server

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 00f095e8-xxxxx-460c-9294-xxxxxxxx
      userAuthorizationUri: https://adfs.teemb.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://localhost:8443/oauth2-example/
      accessTokenUri: https://adfs.teemb.com/adfs/oauth2/token
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      authorizedGrantTypes: authorization_code
      preEstablishedRedirectUri: https://localhost:8443/oauth2-example/login
      useCurrentUri: false
      tokenName: code
      authenticationScheme: query
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://adfs.teemb.com/adfs/oauth2/token/userinfo

logging:
  level:
    com.millsofmn.example: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"

Config file Eclipse.Init im imported

-vmargs
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-1.8/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"

Error when run project :

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
2024-04-09 19:08:20 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2024-04-09 19:08:20 - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@43e570df
2024-04-09 19:08:20 - No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
2024-04-09 19:08:20 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2024-04-09 19:08:20 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    

I have researched on the internet, in general this error is because Eclipse's JVM cannot find the path of Cacerts in the Java environment. I have configured according to the instructions in the Eclipse.Init file and restarted Eclipse, but I still get the problem. error unable to find valid certification path to requested target and no solution
Hope for your Support
